# How to filter by current date using SwiftData and @Query

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

Im currently trying to query records following a given date in SwiftData but get an error (provided below).

**Any idea on how I could go about filtering after the current date using the @Query macro?**

```
/var/folders/3j/pcqx3w012xs_6jc8_ct5vsbc0000gn/T/swift-generated-sources/@__swiftmacro_5Hurry18ArchivedEventsViewV5QueryfMp_9PredicatefMf0_.swift:2:26 Cannot convert value of type 'PredicateExpressions.Comparison<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable<Array<FestivalItem>.Element>, Date>, PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Value<Date.Type>, Date>>' (aka 'PredicateExpressions.Comparison<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable<FestivalItem>, Date>, PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Value<Date.Type>, Date>>') to closure result type 'any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>'
```

```swift
struct ArchivedEventsView: View {
    @Query(filter: #Predicate { $0.startDate > Date.now },
           sort: \FestivalItem.startDate
    ) var festivals: [FestivalItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(festivals) { festival in
                        NavigationLink(value: festival) {
                            EventsCardView(festival: festival)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Archived Events")
            
            .navigationDestination(for: FestivalItem.self) { festival in
                EventsDetailView(festival: festival)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What versions of the SDKs and platforms are you using? `#Predicate` hasn't supported `Date` values throughout the beta process, but the RC release notes do say that should now be fixed. Are you on the most recent version?

Comment: Im on the RC of Xcode. I was able to figure it out though (see answer).

Answer (score 1):

The approach to this would be to create an extension of the `FestivalItem` model class with functions returning a predicate.

```swift
extension FestivalItem {
    
    static func currentPredicate() -> Predicate<FestivalItem> {
        let currentDate = Date.now

        return #Predicate<FestivalItem> { festival in
            festival.endDate > currentDate
        }
    }

    static func pastPredicate() -> Predicate<FestivalItem> {
        let currentDate = Date.now

        return #Predicate<FestivalItem> { festival in
            festival.endDate < currentDate
        }
    }
}
```

And then calling it like so:

```swift
     @Query(filter: FestivalItem.currentPredicate(),
           sort: \FestivalItem.startDate
    ) var festivals: [FestivalItem]
```